# How to fix "vertical alignment ListView in widget - the size of height sometimes less than text content"

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm creating widget where I'm using ListView in RelativeLayout where parent is Linear Layout.

Showing ListView work almost always right!, but sometimes height of the ListView is less than the real wrap_content. Example is visible on screenshots.

The height of ListView is randomly OK or WRONG. I can not find, where is the problem.

My intent is to have ListView centered vertically in the widget.

Used RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory.

You can check the XML files attached.

And screenshots for better understand the issue.
[Right Height](https://raspirarium.com/coding/screenshots/1.jpg) | [Wrong Height](https://raspirarium.com/coding/screenshots/2.jpg)

---

### Widget.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutWidgetScrollable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewVectorArrowL"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:contentDescription="@string/share_quote_button" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutWidgetScrollable"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewWidget"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:foregroundGravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"

            android:layout_margin="0dp"

            android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
            android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"

            android:scrollbars="none"
            />
        <!--sibling with empty view for ListView-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewVectorArrowR"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:contentDescription="@string/share_quote_button" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewVectorButton"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="-24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-24dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/share_quote_button" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewVectorButtonTts"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="-24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-24dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/share_quote_button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

### Row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewFortudeInListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/widget_initializing_title"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/widget_initializing_title"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewAuthorInListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/widget_initializing_title"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I expected that Show ListView get always right height size of ListView as the text size equal. Actually, as it should be.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Vojtech, thank you.

I added SystemClock.sleep to the folowing code and It Works.

```
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
    SystemClock.sleep(50);
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_row);
```

Again Thanks!

Comment: Since this is ListView processing via RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory, delaying the element's return helped.

This will have to do with the preparation of the object in XML and its delivery for rendering.